# SKView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates doesn't work under applicationWillResignActive

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uiapplicationdelegate

I add a pause menu to my SKScene when my spritekit game goes inactive, and I'd like it (the pause menu) to show up in the snapshot the system takes to display in the multitasking app switcher.

Under `applicationWillResignActive` I call `[mySKView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES]` after I add the pause menu to my scene, but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the taken snapshot.

XCode's debug quicklook preview shows the pause menu when I preview my SKScene, but a quicklook preview on mySkscene.view shows that the view remains outdated (it doesn't reflect the new state of the scene), which is presumably what causes the outdated snapshot.

Is there anyway I can get my skview to reflect my last minute change to my SKScene?